# Extracting particular fields in a single file traversal

Tags: shell, awk

I have a requirement. I am in the process of writing awk scripts and my input file is

`TIME FIELD : SOME FIELDS  SOME FIELDS Some fields Some fields RID ..`

The occurrence of RID is random and it varies from one record to another record and, so the problem is I will not be able to use NR and $1 concept as there is no guarantee that RID would occur in this particular line

I need to extract both the time field and RID. I can do that in two file traversal but any idea of how to do it in a single file traversal using awk. Thank you

Comment: How do you extract it on the second traversal? It is not clear from the question how to differentiate it from other fields.

Comment: yes the only identification of RID is that the field starts with RID, all the other field would be something else 
So i can use grep -o "RID=[0-9|A-Z]*" to get this and the same command with grep -o "TIMEFIELD=[0-9|A-Z]*" to get the 
time .. So there are two file traversals. But I wanted this to be done in a single file traversal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
sed 's,^\([^:]*\):.*\(RID=[[:alnum:]]*\).*$,\1 : \2,'
```

It requires the TIME FIELD not to contain any colons though, so please specify a concrete example if that is the case.

I was playing with this input:

```
$ echo 'TIME FIELD : SOME RID=62 FIELDS SOME FIELDS Some fields Some fields
TIME FIELD : SOME FIELDS SOME FIELDS Some fields Some fields RID=012
TIME FIELD : SOME FIELDS RID=5672 SOME FIELDS Some fields Some fields
TIME FIELD : SOME RID=62 FIELDS SOME FIELDS Some fields Some fields' | 
    sed 's,^\([^:]*\):.*\(RID=[[:alnum:]]*\).*$,\1 : \2,'
TIME FIELD  : RID=62
TIME FIELD  : RID=012
TIME FIELD  : RID=5672
TIME FIELD  : RID=62
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. I would try this and let u know

Answer (score 0):

To do it in AWK (assuming the time field doesn't have any spaces or colons within it):

```
awk -F '[: ]' '{for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {if ($i ~ /^RID/) {rid = $i}}; print $1, rid}' inputfile
```

Using only regular expressions without an explicit loop:

```
awk -F ':|RID=' '{split($3, a, " "); print $1, "RID=" a[1]}'
```